# How to groupby on a index column in pyspark pandas?

Tags: python, spark-koalas, pyspark-pandas

I have a pandas API for spark (Koala) dataframe as below,

```py
         c1   c2
id name
a1 a     1    1
a1 b     2    2
b1 c     3    3
```

How can I do groupby like below,

```py
df.groupby(level=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

reset the level first:

```
df.reset_index(level=1).groupby('name').sum()
```